# How to convert C functions to C++?

Tags: c++, c, file

I have a problem because this is my first time encountering some functions from C that I need to convert into C++.

Code:

```
FILE *pokf;
char name[10],gender;
int age, i, n, b1=0, b2=0;
float p;

pokf=fopen("Data.txt","r");       
while (feof(pokf)==0) {
fscanf (pokf,"%s %c %d %f", &name, &gender, &age, &p);
if (gender=='Z') b1++;
if (p>=4.50 ) b2++;  }
fclose(pokf);
```

I can write:

```
ifstream input;
input.open("Data.txt");
```

But then I don't know what to use instead of pokf because I can't use FILE *pokf anymore.
What to use instead of functions feof and fscanf?

Comment: I recommend investing in [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). They should have all the information you need for this (and more).

Comment: The C code is low quality, written by someone who doesn't really know what they're doing.

Comment: It's not clear what you really want here.  The title question is incredibly broad, but you seem actually to want something very much more specific.  But if it's just a question of how to use C++ stream classes then I am confident that you would be better served by looking up one of the many tutorials on that topic around the web, or even by reading the classes' documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The rough equivalent of `fscanf` is `operator>>` and I wouldn't worry about `feof` since it's being used incorrectly. So

```
while (feof(pokf)==0) {
    fscanf (pokf,"%s %c %d %f", &name, &gender, &age, &p);
    ...
```

becomes

```
while (pokf >> name >> gender >> age >> p) {
    ...
```

Although using `char name[10]` in C++ will work, it has the obvious problem that you are limited to names of 9 characters of less. In C++ you should use `std::string` instead of a char array.

Comment: I got an error: [Error] invalid operands of types 'FILE* {aka _iobuf*}' and 'char' to binary 'operator>>'

Comment: @zastacka2345 I was assuming that you'd changed `pokf` to an `ifstream` (like you said in your question).

Comment: It's working now. Problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use FILE *pokf in c++, here is an example http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/ where you can see how to open files in c++

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file"; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but  I should use C++ syntax.

Comment: IMO that is c++ syntax aswell as C but if you must use ifstream you can do something like this to read a file (i edited my answer so you can see it formated)